# Plotly Dendrogram with Heat Map

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to reproduce this amazing plotly interactive graph:-

[https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~jackp/6748/dendrogram-heatmap/#/plot](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Ejackp/6748/dendrogram-heatmap/#/plot)

However, I keep getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax for:-

```
"zauto": True, 
       ^
```

...which is in this statement:-

```
import plotly
import plotly.chart_studio
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
py.sign_in('username', 'api_key')

trace1 = {
  "uid": "4817b6", 
  "line": {"width": 1}, 
  "meta": {"columnNames": {
      "x": "trace0_x", 
      "y": "trace0_y"
    }}, 
  "mode": "lines", 
  "type": "scatter", 
  "xsrc": "kehliah:0:351400", 
  "x": [15, 15, 25, 25], 
  "ysrc": "kehliah:0:58645b", 
  "y": [0, 99157.34038285201, 99157.34038285201, 0], 
  "yaxis": "y2", 
  "marker": {"color": "rgb(255,133,27)"}
}
# trace2 through trace138 skipped
trace139 = {
  "uid": "3f3555", 
  "meta": {"columnNames": {
      "x": "trace138_x", 
      "y": "trace138_y", 
      "z": "long list"
    }}, 
  "type": "heatmap", 
  "xsrc": "0:1d26f7", 
  "x": [long, list],
  "ysrc": "0:292f1a", 
  "y": [long, list],
  "zmax": 155160.122245, 
  "zmin": 0, 
  "zsrc": "long,list", 
  "z": [long, list],
  "zauto": True, <--------- error
  "opacity": 1, 
  "zsmooth": False, 
  "colorbar": {
    "x": 0.96, 
    "y": 0.9, 
    "len": 1, 
    "xpad": 0, 
    "ticks": "", 
    "title": {
      "font": {
        "size": 12, 
        "color": "#444", 
        "family": "\"Open sans\", verdana, arial, sans-serif"
      }, 
      "side": "top", 
      "text": ""
    }, 
    "nticks": 0, 
    "bgcolor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", 
    "lenmode": "fraction", 
    "xanchor": "right", 
    "yanchor": "top", 
    "autotick": True, 
    "tickfont": {
      "size": 12, 
      "color": "#444", 
      "family": "\"Open sans\", verdana, arial, sans-serif"
    }, 
    "thickness": 20, 
    "tickangle": "auto", 
    "bordercolor": "#444", 
    "borderwidth": 0, 
    "outlinecolor": "#444", 
    "outlinewidth": 1, 
    "showexponent": "all", 
    "thicknessmode": "pixels", 
    "exponentformat": "B", 
    "showticklabels": True
  }, 
  "showscale": True, 
  "colorscale": [
    [0, "rgb(5, 10, 172)"], [0.35, "rgb(106, 137, 247)"], [0.5, "rgb(190,190,190)"], [0.6, "rgb(220, 170, 132)"], [0.7, "rgb(230, 145, 90)"], [1, "rgb(178, 10, 28)], 
  "reversescale": False
}
layout = {
  "title": {"text": "Dendrogram Heatmap"}, 
  "width": 1400, 
  "xaxis": {
    "type": "linear", 
    "range": [0, 960], 
    "ticks": "", 
    "title": {"text": ""}, 
    "domain": [0.15, 0.9], 
    "mirror": "allticks", 
    "showgrid": False, 
    "showline": False, 
    "tickmode": "array", 
    "ticktext": ["2010012O05Rik", "3110007F17Rik", "4732471J01Rik", "4930470H14Rik", "4930511M06Rik", "9030612E09Rik", "A130077B15Rik", "A630089N07Rik", "AY761184", "Acer2", "Actb", "Agr2", "Apoa1", "Apoa4", "Apoc3", "Atg5", "Atp5e", "B2m", "Ccdc82", "Chgb", "Crip1", "Ctla2a", "Defa-rs1", "Defa-rs7", "Defa17", "Defa22", "Defa23", "Defa24", "Defa3", "Emg1", "Fabp1", "Foxo1", "Fuca1", "Gchfr", "Ggact", "Gm14851", "Gm15284", "Gm15308", "Gm16702", "Gm17644", "Gm17821", "Gm20300", "Gm20594", "Gm5766", "Gm7849", "Gngt2", "Grk4", "H2-Ab1", "H2-Q4", "Hint1", "Hsbp1", "Ifi47", "Itln1", "Lce3a", "Lypd8", "Mir3470b", "Mir3473f", "Mir682", "Mrfap1", "Mrpl14", "Mrpl2", "NR_003279", "Ndufb4", "Olfr856-ps1", "Pax6", "Pepd", "Ppia", "Prap1", "Psmb1", "Psme2", "Rab10os", "Rapgef4", "Reg1", "Reg3g", "Rnase4", "Rnu6", "Rpl17", "Rps8", "S100b", "Sec11a", "Selk", "Slc6a19", "Smco1", "Spink4", "Sprr2b", "Synj2bp", "Tceb1", "Tff3", "Timm10", "Tm4sf5", "Tmigd3", "Tmsb10", "Vmn1r58", "Ywhaq", "Zfp488", "Zfp65"], 
    "tickvals": [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 105, 115, 125, 135, 145, 155, 165, 175, 185, 195, 205, 215, 225, 235, 245, 255, 265, 275, 285, 295, 305, 315, 325, 335, 345, 355, 365, 375, 385, 395, 405, 415, 425, 435, 445, 455, 465, 475, 485, 495, 505, 515, 525, 535, 545, 555, 565, 575, 585, 595, 605, 615, 625, 635, 645, 655, 665, 675, 685, 695, 705, 715, 725, 735, 745, 755, 765, 775, 785, 795, 805, 815, 825, 835, 845, 855, 865, 875, 885, 895, 905, 915, 925, 935, 945, 955], 
    "zeroline": False, 
    "autorange": True, 
    "rangemode": "tozero", 
    "showticklabels": True
  }, 
  "yaxis": {
    "type": "linear", 
    "range": [0, 457.89473684210526], 
    "ticks": "", 
    "title": {"text": ""}, 
    "domain": [0, 0.78], 
    "mirror": "allticks", 
    "showgrid": False, 
    "showline": False, 
    "tickmode": "array", 
    "ticktext": ["P3_B10: 0", "P3_A1: 0", "P3_A12: 0", "P3_B4: 0", "P3_E5: 0", "P3_H1: 0", "P3_B5: 0", "P3_F5: 0", "P3_F12: 0", "P3_A7: 0", "P3_D12: 0", "P3_E6: 0", "P3_D10: 0", "P3_F11: 0", "P3_F10: 0", "P3_G10: 0", "P3_D11: 0", "P3_B12: 0", "P3_H3: 0", "P3_D2: 0", "P3_G12: 0", "P3_E2: 0", "P3_B1: 0", "P3_C10: 0", "P3_A9: 0", "P3_B7: 1", "P3_A2: 1", "P3_B8: 1", "P3_E12: 1", "P3_E3: 1", "P3_E8: 1", "P3_F6: 1", "P3_F8: 1", "P3_A8: 1", "P3_C2: 1", "P3_B6: 1", "P3_C7: 1", "P3_C3: 1", "P3_F1: 1", "P3_H4: 1", "P3_E7: 1", "P3_E4: 1", "P3_F7: 1", "P3_G3: 1"], 
    "tickvals": [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 105, 115, 125, 135, 145, 155, 165, 175, 185, 195, 205, 215, 225, 235, 245, 255, 265, 275, 285, 295, 305, 315, 325, 335, 345, 355, 365, 375, 385, 395, 405, 415, 425, 435], 
    "zeroline": False, 
    "autorange": True, 
    "rangemode": "tozero", 
    "showticklabels": True
  }, 
  "bargap": 0, 
  "height": 1000, 
  "margin": {
    "l": 20, 
    "r": 20, 
    "t": 50, 
    "autoexpand": True
  }, 
  "xaxis2": {
    "type": "linear", 
    "range": [-164839.4813992131, 0], 
    "ticks": "", 
    "title": {"text": ""}, 
    "domain": [0, 0.1], 
    "showgrid": False, 
    "showline": False, 
    "tickmode": "array", 
    "zeroline": False, 
    "autorange": True
  }, 
  "yaxis2": {
    "type": "linear", 
    "range": [-23014.5471171554, 437276.39522595255], 
    "ticks": "outside", 
    "title": {"text": ""}, 
    "domain": [0.75, 1], 
    "showgrid": False, 
    "showline": False, 
    "tickmode": "array", 
    "zeroline": False, 
    "autorange": True, 
    "overlaying": False
  }, 
  "autosize": False, 
  "autoscale": False, 
  "hovermode": "closest", 
  "showlegend": False
}
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.plot(fig)
```

It is not clear to me why this is failing, but it is an 8 year old example. When I remove zauto, it then fails at the opacity statement, and then when that is removed it fails at zsmooth, etc. In short, it really does not like trace139 at all. Is there an updated way to produce such a plot in plotly 5.16.1?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the downloaded Python code was mildly malformed, and the errors thrown because of them were misleading. After some clean-up, everything started to work as expected. Unfortunately, the code blocks are too large to paste. The main thing to look out for is trace139: it had a couple of missing "]" brackets to close lists.